# submit button doesnot hides when 'check-all' checkbox is unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to make a page where submit button show/hides when a checkbox is checked. The same I want to do with the 'check-all' and currently when check-all is checked, the submit button appears but when the 'check-all' gets unchecked the submit button does not hides. Although the listed checkboxes perforn absolutely fine but only the unchecking of 'check-all' does not makes the submit button hide.

here is my code, please let me know where I am going wrong and if there is any solution for it.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="all_check[]" class="checkbox" value= "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/> </th>  //this is my 'check-all'

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> value= "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"class="checkbox" id="select_all" >  //this is my listed checkboxes under the 'check-all'
```

and here is my jquery,

```
$(function(){
    $('[type=checkbox]').click(function ()
    {
        var checkedChbx = $('[type=checkbox]:checked');
        if (checkedChbx.length > 0)
        {
            $('#one').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#one').hide();
        }
    });
});


  $(document).ready(function() {

        var $submit = $("#one").hide(),
            $cbs = $('input[name="all_check[]"]').click(function() {
                $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
            });

    });
```

Comment: Add a fiddle for make us understand what your code or you want to do.

Comment: can I have a link on how to make a fiddle. I am new in here so an advice would be helpful.

Comment: Here you can make [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Or Stackoverflow(SO) has it's own snippet you can use it, Press ctrl+m when asking questions to make snippets.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't store the selector in the $submit variable, try:

```
var $submit = $("#one");
        $submit.hide();
           var $cbs = $('input[name="all_check[]"]').click(function() {
                $submit.toggle( $(this).is(":checked") );//use this to get the current clicked element 
            });
```

change the selector for the first click event to

```
 $('input[name="check[]"]').click(function () {....
```

demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="check[]"]').click(function() {
    var checkedChbx = $('[type=checkbox]:checked');
    if (checkedChbx.length > 0) {
      $('#one').show();
    } else {
      $('#one').hide();
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  var $submit = $("#one");
  $submit.hide();
  var $cbs = $('input[name="all_check[]"]').click(function() {
  $('input[name="check[]"]').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
    $submit.toggle($(this).is(":checked")); //use this to get the current clicked element 
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="all_check[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /> </th> //this is my 'check-all'

<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="checkbox" id="select_all">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="checkbox" id="select_all">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="checkbox" id="select_all">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="checkbox" id="select_all">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="checkbox" id="select_all"> //this is my listed checkboxes under the 'check-all'
<button id="one">one</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the concern mate. But changing your suggest also not working. It still doesnot goes away on unchecking the 'check-all'

Comment: no success mate. Using this code now does not shows submit button on 'check-all'. earlier is was there.   <input type="submit" name ="all_send" value="Approve" style="display: none"  id="one" class="btn btn-success"> //this is my submit button @madalinivascu

Comment: did you checked my demo?

Comment: yes I did. but there also when check-all is clicked it does not checks all the listed checkboxes  @madalinivascu

Comment: you will need `$('input[name="check[]"]').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));` for that see updated snippet

Comment: THANKS A TON !!!!! Its exactly performing as expected. Saved my day. @madalinivascu

Answer (score 2):

Here is Example how to You hide when all check box is unchecked....

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
  if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0)
  {
    $("input[type=submit]").show();
  }
  else{ 
    $("input[type=submit]").hide(); 
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type=submit]").hide(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" />check 1
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" />check 2
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" />check 3

<input type=submit />
```

Comment: Thanks for concern but actually this didn't solve the issue . @ChiragSuthar

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[name='check']").on('change',function(){
  if( $("input[name='check']:checked").length>0)
     $("input[type='submit']").fadeIn();
  else
     $("input[type='submit']").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
<input type="submit" value"submit" style="display:none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".YourCheckBoxClass").change(function() {
    $('#YourSubmitButtonID').prop('disabled', $(".check_class").filter(':checked').length < 1);
});
$(".YourCheckBoxClass").change();
</script>
```